# update database via SQL

Tags: c#, sql, textbox, oledb

i'm trying to update my code with values that already exist there(in the same row) and I get the error below.

here is the code:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Projects_2012\\Project_Noam\\Access\\myProject.accdb";
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

string myInsertQuery = (String.Format("UPDATE tblUsers SET usersID='{0}', usersFirstName='{1}', " +
" usersLastName='{2}',usersPassword='{3}', usersAdress='{4}', usersMail  ='{5}' " +
" WHERE usersID='{6}'", idn, firstName.Text, lastName.Text, password.Text, adress.Text
, mail.Text,  idn));

OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myInsertQuery);
myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
myConnection.Open();
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myCommand.Connection.Close();
```

here is the error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException crossed a native / managed boundary
Message = mismatch in criteria expression
Source = Microsoft Office Access Database Engine
ErrorCode = -2147217913
```

the parameters in my database are defined like this :"usersID=number" and the rest as text.

Comment: Wow, the possibilities for SQL Injection with this...

Comment: Do some research on using parameterized queries (think: OleDbParameter) and save yourself some future heartache.

Comment: Since your userid is number field, you can make it like `UPDATE tblUsers SET usersID={0}`

Comment: @Rahul  i get the same error although your fix.

Comment: @Tejs so how it will be looked like? i have never used sql injection

Comment: @Noam, change the same suggested in `where clause as well` like `WHERE usersID={6}`. Also, you don't need to pass the same id twice. Your where clause can be `WHERE usersID={0}`

Comment: Everyone who interacts with a db should read [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First start using parameterized query. See [OleDbParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx). Also read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The error you are getting usually happens when the database is expecting value of one type and you are providing other. In you case it looks like your userID is of type integer and since you are enclosing it in single quote you are getting this error. Try the following query(the changed part is `userID={0}`). EDIT: Same should be changed in the where clause.

```
string myInsertQuery = (String.Format("UPDATE tblUsers SET usersID={0}, usersFirstName='{1}', " +
                " usersLastName='{2}',usersPassword='{3}', usersAdress='{4}', usersMail  ='{5}' " +
                " WHERE usersID={6}", idn, firstName.Text, lastName.Text, password.Text, adress.Text
                , mail.Text,  idn));
```

Comment: `userID={0})` Correct but the same change should in `where` as well; like `WHERE usersID={6}`. Why not change that?

Comment: thank u so much and @Rahul too :) I am so stupid for missing that!